# Shorten Dynamic SQL Query For Loop

Tags: javascript, sql

I have a function that builds an sql query and then inserts it into the client-side light sql.

I think im using to many for loops, how would i make this shorter?

```
function insert(dataBase,table,row){
    var j = 0;

    var sqlQueryArray = [];

    sqlQueryArray[j++] = 'INSERT INTO ';
    sqlQueryArray[j++] = table
    sqlQueryArray[j++] = ' ('

    for (var i = row.length - 2; i >= 0; i--){
        sqlQueryArray[j++] = row[i].id + ',';
    };

    sqlQueryArray[j++] = row[(row.length - 1)].id + '';
    sqlQueryArray[j++] = ')'
    var sqlQueryString = ' VALUES ';

    for (var i = row.length - 2; i >= 0; i--){
        sqlQueryArray[j++] = '?, ';
    };

    sqlQueryArray[j++] = '?';
    sqlQueryArray[j++] = ');'

    for (var i = 0; i < sqlQueryArray.length; i++){
        sqlQueryString += sqlQueryArray[i];
    }
    var rowArray = []
    for (var i = row.length - 1; i >= 0; i--){
        rowArray[i] = row[i].val;
    };

    dataBase.openDatabase.transaction(
        function (transaction) {
            transaction.executeSql(sqlQueryString,
                rowArray,
                dataBase.nullSQLHandler, dataBase.QueryError);
        }
    );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're using a relatively recent browser, you *could* do something like this:

```
var insertStatement =
   'INSERT INTO ' + table +
   ' (' + rows.map(function (row) { return row.id; }).join(', ') + ')' +
   ' VALUES (' + rows.map(function () { return '?'; }).join(', ') + ')';
```

Whether you *should* or not is left as an exercise for the reader :)

**Edit**: I just noticed in a comment to another answer that you are sending this to the server for execution. You should definitely *not* do that, since a user could easily submit their own SQL and wreak all kinds of havoc on your database. You shouldn't trust any data received over the network.

Comment: Most of the info that is going into the client sql is from the server over an ssl socket. Im trying to make it very automated plus the client would be a mobile phone. I think sending most of the grunt work to the server might take a load of the client.

Answer (score 1):

Whenver Dynamic SQL is created in an application, things are unleashed and children are eaten.

You should really use a parameterized SP for this one for a multitude of security and performance reasons (not to mention readability/maintainability).

Comment: Your right I might more the query building to the server. It would make the sql more asynchronous.

Comment: Oh... you're sending the query to the server for execution?

Comment: Right now Im doing it on the client side, but the server is a node.js server. So i might just send (table,row) and get a string with a value array.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I think you'd be better not tracking the index manually (`j++`). Use sqlQueryArray.push() to insert the elements at the end of `sqlQueryArray`.

Then, to simplify your code, you can create a function that returns you a custom SQL passing your `row` variable as a parameter, with that you can generate the `INSERT INTO` clause with all the `?` markers.